# TYPO3 Extbase - static_info_tables how to map country field?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I created an extension with the Extension Builder and inserted the model class for my countries table:

\SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country

When I save the extension the Builder warns me with
The configuration for table "static_countries" is not compatible with extbase. You have to configure it yourself if you want to map to this table  (Error 606)

I tried to read the manual but I couldnt find a way how to map it in my extension. In the backend the dropdown works fine but in the Extension I only get uid from the model

Comment: Please show us the configuration for table "static_countries" and tel us which TYPO3 version you use.

Comment: It's a brand new development so TYPO3 v10.4 and static_info_tables 6.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is searching for this .. I finally managed or understood how to do it.

1. add

> use SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Country;

in your Domain\Model\countries.php or whatever it's called

2. change the default

> class Countries extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity

that the extension_builder generates to extend the static_info_tables model:

> class Countries extends Country

Thats it. Now you get all properties from the countries table